# Convert dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this dictionary:

```
data = ({"Jan 2018":1000},{"Feb 2018":1100},{"Mar 2018":1400},{"Apr 2018":700},{"May 2018":800})
data
```

to dataframe like:

```
date       balance
Jan 2018   1000
Feb 2018   1100
Mar 2018   1400
Apr 2018   700
May 2018   800
```

I used the dataframe to convert, but it didn't give the format as above, how can i do it? Thank you!

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_c, orient='columns')
```

Comment: And if you replace in your data ( )  by [ ] ?

Comment: That's not a dictionary. Why are you using a tuple instead of a list, and why a bunch of dictionaries? That's the bigger issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ({"Jan 2018":1000},{"Feb 2018":1100},{"Mar 2018":1400},{"Apr 2018":700},{"May 2018":800})

arr = [list(*d.items()) for d in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['data', 'balance'])
```

you need get proper array from the tuple of dictionary before pass it to DataFrame.

Comment: Doesn’t this solution rely on there being only 1 element in each dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: v for d in data for k, v in d.items()}, 
                             orient='index', 
                             columns=['balance']).rename_axis('date').reset_index()

Out[477]:
       date  balance
0  Jan 2018     1000
1  Feb 2018     1100
2  Mar 2018     1400
3  Apr 2018      700
4  May 2018      800
```

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: it is just my preference to use dict comprehension. `dict.update` still needs a for loop to get each element of `data` to pass to it. Calling `d_1.update(data)` won't work because `data` is tuples of dicts.

Comment: Yeah, the loop is unfortunate. It just feels so odd seeing `{k: v for k, v in....}`.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation of `from_dict`

> orient : {‘columns’, ‘index’}, default ‘columns’
>
> The “orientation” of the data. If the keys of the passed dict should be the columns of the resulting DataFrame, pass ‘columns’ (default). Otherwise if the keys should be rows, pass ‘index’.

Since you want your keys to indicate rows, changing the `orient` to `index` will give the result your want. However first you need to put your data in a single dictionary. This code will give you the result you want.

```
data = ({"Jan 2018":1000},{"Feb 2018":1100},{"Mar 2018":1400},{"Apr 2018":700},{"May 2018":800})

d = {}
for i in data:
    for k in i.keys():
        d[k] = i[k]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Answer (score -2):

What you have there is a tuple of single-element dictionaries. This is unidiomatic, and poor design. If all the dictionaries correspond to the same columns, then a list of tuples would do just fine.

---

### Solutions

I believe the currently accepted answer relies on there being only one key:value pair in each dictionary. That’s unfortunate, since it automatically excludes most situations where this design makes any sense.

---

If, hypothetically, the "tuple of 1-element dicts" couldn't be changed, here is how I would suggest doing things:

```py
import pandas as pd
import itertools as itt

raw_data = ({"Jan 2018": 1000}, {"Feb 2018": 1100}, {"Mar 2018": 1400}, {"Apr 2018": 700}, {"May 2018": 800})

data = itt.chain.from_iterable(curr.items() for curr in raw_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'balance'])
```

---

Here is the sensible alternative to all this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [("Jan 2018", 1000), ("Feb 2018", 1100), ("Mar 2018", 1400), ("Apr 2018", 700), ("May 2018", 800)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'balance'])
```

`df`:

```
       date  balance
0  Jan 2018     1000
1  Feb 2018     1100
2  Mar 2018     1400
3  Apr 2018      700
4  May 2018      800
```

It would probably be even better if those dates were actual date types, not strings. I will change that later.