# Dictionary to DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I checked many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59314730/convert-dictionaries-to-dataframe) from here but it is not totally the same as my problem.

Let's create a dummy dictionary to describe my problem.

```
dictionary = {12: {1,2,4,6,8,12,16,65,13,644,653,23}, 15:{10,20,30,23,56,6,8,}, 17:{4,7,11,12,19}, 20:{40,54,123,545,234}}
```

Here the keys are userid, values are location-id.

My goal is to create a dataframe like this

```
userid locationid
12        1
12        2
12        4
...       ...
15        20
15        30
15        23
...       ...
17         4
17         7
17         11
...        ...
20         40
20         54
...       ...
```

My solution

```
for dictkey in range(len(dictionary.keys())): 
        lids = list(np.array(list(dictionary.values())[dictkey]).item())
        userid = np.array(list(dictionary.keys())[dictkey])
        userid = userid.reshape(1,1)
        df= pd.DataFrame(userid, columns =['userid'])
        df['locationid'] = lids
```

but it doesn't work. How should I approach the problem? I could not solve

Note: Normally my real dataset is big.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can convert to series then explode:

```
pd.Series(dictionary).map(list).explode()
```

---

```
12      1
12      2
12     65
12      4
12    644
12      6
12      8
12     12
12     13
12    653
12     16
12     23
15      6
15      8
15     10
15     20
15     23
15     56
15     30
17      4
17      7
17     11
17     12
17     19
20    545
20     40
20    234
20     54
20    123
dtype: object
```

Or for higher versions of pandas >= 1.2.0, one can also use (thanks @[aneroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431750/aneroid))

```
pd.Series(dictionary).explode()
```

Comment: very nice solution

Comment: @anky FWIW, `pd.Series(dictionary).explode()` directly also works.

Comment: @aneroid thank you :) I was wondering why didnt they implement it. For my version `0.25.1` it doesnot work. But glad to know they have implemented explode on the values. BDW what id your pandas version?

Comment: @anky That would explain it; I'm on v1.2.1. I think [exploding **Sets** was added in 1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html). The [docs for 0.25.1 and 0.25.3 don't mention Sets](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).

Comment: @aneroid thank you for your research :) do you mind if I add your suggestion in the solution?

Comment: and this code block returns a list, if you add it to the code that will turn the list into dataframe , I think it would be better.

Comment: @anky Yes, pls do! I was going to suggest the same, for future visitors :-)

Comment: @anky Maybe rephrase that to "versions of pandas >= `1.2.0`" instead of _"...than `0.25.1`"_ since `0.25.3` doesn't have it. Btw I checked further, [1.2.0 is the first version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) of the docs which specify that it works on Sets.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.concat` and `pd.DataFrame.stack`

```
>>> pd.concat([pd.Series(list(val), name=k) for k, val in dictionary.items()], 
               axis=1
              ).stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).sort_index()
               .rename_axis('uderId').to_frame('locationid')

        locationid
uderId            
12            65.0
12           653.0
12            13.0
12            12.0
12             8.0
12             6.0
12           644.0
12            16.0
12             4.0
12            23.0
12             2.0
12             1.0
15            56.0
15            23.0
15            30.0
15             8.0
15            10.0
15             6.0
15            20.0
17             7.0
17            19.0
17            11.0
17             4.0
17            12.0
20           234.0
20           545.0
20            54.0
20            40.0
20           123.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the dictionary `12: {1,2,3}` to `[(12,1),(12,2),(12,3)]` using `itertools.product` and then finally create the dataframe

```py
import itertools
data = []
for k,v in dictionary.items():
    data.extend(list(itertools.product([k],v)))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['userid', 'locationid'])
```